# fatal error: 'future' file not found

Tags: eosio.cdt, contract-development

I want to write a contract by using [CPR](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr) library. Unfortunately I have an error:

```
fatal error: 'future' file not found
#include <future>
```

I am using EOSIO cdt v1.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I had the same with v1.4.1. I have build the v1.5.0 from the source hoping it will have needed header because I see a file ./libraries/libc++/libcxx/src/future.cpp in the repo.

Can you please help me?

Comment: i am facing the same issue while making a smart contract using **cpr** library,did you get any work around it? or any other library instead of cpr that works with eosio? I am using eosio.cdt 1.6.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: No, I dropped that little project.Now I am focused on other that does not have such need to use `future` .

Comment: I see, but is there any way to implement response request of API in smart contract in eosio? and did you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to use `future` in smart contracts, because the whole thing is single-thread C++. Multithreading isn't supported and wouldn't work within the contract because it would potentially make the results of any code non-deterministic

Comment: I understand your opinion, but I found a 'thread' header file in eosio.cdt directory.
file /usr/local/eosio.cdt/include/libcxx/thread

Comment: It isn't an opinion. If the smart contract was non-deterministic, then it wouldn't make sense to have it on a blockchain. Sorry but thats kind of in the definition. Perhaps B1 forgot to take it away when they built their libraries?